# PHP PDO MySql lastInsertId() returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

I have the following code which i have extracted and simplified from the site. This code works fine with just a few fields

But i am unable to get lastInsertId() working, it always returns a 0

Please help

```
<?php 

class Db {
  private $host = "localhost";
  private $user = "root";
  private $pwd = "";
  private $dbName = "cms";

  public function connect() {
      
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pwd);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    return $pdo;
  }
}


class Jobs extends Db {
    
     public function addJob($job_date_time, $job_type, $job_decs) {
         
        $sql = "INSERT INTO jobs(job_date_time, job_type, job_decs) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        
        $stmt->execute([$job_date_time, $job_type, $job_decs]);
        
        $lastId = $this->connect()->lastInsertId();
        echo $lastId; 
    
        
      }
}     

    

    $jobs = new Jobs();
    
    $job_date_time      = "2021-11-11T11:40";
    $job_type           = "Test Type";
    $job_desc           = "Test Desc";
  
    $jobs->addJob($job_date_time, $job_type, $job_desc);
```

Answer (score 2):

`lastInsertId()` only returns the last auto-increment id generated if you call that function in the same session the id was generated in.

Every time you call `$this->connect()` it opens a new connection, thus it's a new session and any state from the previous session (e.g. the last insert id) is reset.

You might have intended `$this->connect()` to skip creating a new connection if it already has one.

```
class Db {
  private $host = "localhost";
  private $user = "root";
  private $pwd = "";
  private $dbName = "cms";
  private $pdo;

  public function connect() {

    if (!$this->pdo) {
      $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName;
      $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pwd);
      $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    return $this->pdo;
  }
}
```

This opens a new connection the first time you call `connect()`, but it saves the connection as an object variable. Each subsequent time time you call `connect()` it just uses the same connection it had saved earlier. The connection stays open for the lifespan of this `Db` object.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfect